# Find the thevenin equivalent resistance for the given circuit

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, thevenin

[image: Change everything for the points A,B]

I need to find the equivalent thevenin resistance, everything from the points A,B is exchanged.. however after I construct the image:

[image]

It says the answer is Rth = 100 Ohm, but I can't figure out how, would it be different if I move the points A,B between R2 and R3 and R4 and R5 respectively (the points A&B aren't given , I just have to change the rest of the circuit to a thevenin equivalent and just leave the branch where Rp is.)

I know this is a homework like question, but can someone just explain it to me how would I get to the result, or link to some useful tutorial so I can learn it on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are nearly there so redraw taking into account: -

- R5 is a dead short
- R1 is in parallel with R4 and R6

It does work out at 100 ohms BTW